# Languages that don't have the single classpath issue in Java

Tags: java, hibernate, programming-languages, osgi, classpath

I started to write a piece of software with a group of friends and chose the Java language since we were all familiar with it.

In order to solve the single classpath problem in Java, we chose to use OSGi. We used Spring DM, Hibernate and CXF DOSGi for the project.

It took a lot of effort to get things working. For example, we wanted to use Spring annotations to mark transactions and it was quite a difficult task. We got a lot of `ClassNotFoundException`s and in order to solve them, added imports to the import-package section without knowing exactly why they were needed (these were mainly Spring packages).

After going through the process we thought that maybe we have chosen the wrong language?

So my questions are:

1. What are the languages that do not have the single classpath problem like in Java?
2. How does those languages solve the problem?
3. Are there any cons in using any of those languages rather than using Java (except for the fact that we will have to learn them)?

Comment: What exactly is the single class-path problem???

Comment: @Thihara the fact that we can't use two versions of the same library since only one of them will be used when running. With OSGi, each bundle has its own classpath. See the versioning section [here](http://www.osgi.org/Technology/WhyOSGi).

Comment: That seem to be a seriously bad reason for using osgi

Comment: @Thihara It says that versioning is one of the advantages of OSGi in the OSGi alliance web site under [Why OSGi](http://www.osgi.org/Technology/WhyOSGi).Do you mean to say that the information in the above link is inaccurate? Also, if our software depends on third party libraries, then there is a very good chance that those would depend on different versions of the same library.

Comment: I don't think you've chosen the wrong language; you may have chosen the wrong libraries. Spring, Hibernate and CXF are famously a complete ****ing mess of dependencies; it's no wonder that you have to add lots and lot of imports to use them.

Comment: As for your actual question... are you asking about other JVM languages, or languages outside the Java Platform? The global classpath is an intrinsic feature of the Java Platform and therefore is a problem for **all** JVM languages, including Java, Scala, Groovy, Clojure, etc.

Comment: I also noted that part mentioning it's not advised to create a system like that. Why do you need to use two versions of the same library? Unless you are maintaining a warped system...

Comment: Anyway, if you use a proper tool for OSGi development you will find that it requires a lot less manual effort. For example there is no good reason to write your imports manually... if you use Bndtools these will be calculated automatically.

Comment: @NeilBartlett I was asking about non JVM languages. I assumed that JVM languages would have the problem as you have mentioned.

Comment: @Can'tTell Then the question is too broad. Most languages have some kind of "module path" which loosely corresponds to Java's classpath.

Comment: I don't see the point, [dependency hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell) is a general problem, not specific to Java

Comment: @Katona Do you mean to say that it is a problem that has not been solved yet by any programming language? My question is, is there a language that has a solved the problem? For example OSGi solves it for Java, but it is not a part of the language. I'm asking is there is some language that inherently solves this.

Comment: @Can'tTell OSGi is the best solution for "dependency hell" in any language, that I've seen. The fact that it's not "part of the language" is irrelevant. That just means you can use it for all of the languages available on the JVM, not just Java.

Comment: BTW I voted to close this question because it's too broad and invites opinionated rather than definitive answers.

Comment: @NeilBartlett The reason why I thought that being a part of the language is important is because if the language supported it then it would mean that the language was designed to be modular. And I think the question is quite straightforward. If someone knows a lnaguage that solves the problem, they can simply reply with the name of the language :)

Comment: @Can'tTell now I understand your question, but I don't know the answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not the language. Your problem is that your *technologies* are very unmodular. OSGi is not a library or secret sauce that when added gives you magically all the benefits of modularity, among which your desired multiple 'class spaces'. OSGi provides the fabric for modular applications, that is applications build out of cohesive and minimally coupled components.

You have chosen the popular but highly unmodular technologies like Spring and Hibernate. These technologies are not modular because they heavily rely on a single classspace since they use dynamic class loading (Class.forName) pervasively. I.e. each class name in an XML file is dynamically loaded. Not only does this paradigm require a global class space (these class names are effectively treated as global variables, which is bad as any CS student should know), it also uses the names of implementation classes. Using a name of an implementation class outside its module is the antithesis of modularity. Your ClassNotFoundExceptions are OSGi telling you that somebody does not respect its module fences. That is, modularity has to be in the way you structure your code, OSGi then just provides a substrate to run these modules and enforces their boundaries.

So OSGi has a very elegant and heavily underestimated technology to create very strong modules that do not suffer from global variables and leaking of implementation details: uServices. These uServices are objects specified in a specification package and shared between modules via a lightweight broker. uServices actually void the need of Spring XML.

Unfortunately, the current state of the art is that we have a lot of developers in Java who have grown up believing class loading hacks are how you glue open source projects together.

The good news is that things are moving. Currently a lot of projects start to make their JARs bundles (OSGi is #33 in popularity on maven central) although most ports are just providing headers (using one of most downloaded plugins on maven central). However, once this first step is said, adding services is usually not that hard. I'm hired by the OSGi Alliance to speed up this process. And actually, JPA is on the top of my list!

Back to your original question: as far as I know only Java supports class loaders, a requisite concept for multiple class spaces. All dynamic languages i know bind only by their class name effectively ruling out your requirement. So I am fairly confident that there is actually no alternative ...

Comment: Thanks for a very descriptive answer